# How to use the same link for a specific page in facebook on web and mobile

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, gmail

Im making a mail signature and I need to add an icon that will lead to a facebook page.
My problem is that for web I need to use an http link, and for mobile, (i.e when signature is displayed on mobile browser/mail app ) and I want to open the facebook app and redirect to the required page, I need to use a fb:// link.

I know that I can use an inline js code for device detecting but I really do not want to run a script for mail signature.

Does anyone have a creative idea?

Comment: I do not think that there is another way. Why you do not want to use script for this? It is not neccesary to use JS script, you can do it with php. Check this http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: I'll be surprised if any email client that shows your signature would even run the javascript that you send around. So that approach would be pointless anyway.